# Update deeply nested react redux state array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, redux

I have a redux state array like this

```
[{
    client_id:12,
    template:{
     item1:[],
     item2:[],
     simple templates:[
      "Some paragraph 1",
      "Some paragraph 2",
      "Some paragraph 3",
     ]
    }
}]
```

So I want to update an element on the `simple templates` array using redux immutability helpers https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html. For example I want to update **"Some paragraph 2"** with **"Some paragraph #2"**. I'm passing the data I want to update using a form to the reducers.

So far I have been trying something like this

```
case TEMP_UPDATE_TEMPLATE: {
      console.log('index', action.payload.index); 
      console.log('data', action.payload.data); //new data that I want to update

      return update(state.simple_templates, {
        [0]: {
          template: {
            "Simple Templates": {
              [action.payload.index] : {
                $set: action.payload.data
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
}
```

It's really confusing for me. Please help me to understand how to update an element of deeply nested object array with a given index.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$splice` instead of `$set` as it is an array.

```js
return update(state.simple_templates, {
  [0]: {
    template: {
      "simple templates": {
        $splice: [action.payload.index, 1, action.payload.data]
      }
    }
  }
})
```